# Im working on laravel website where getting an error by google ads team: website has badlink in the scan

Tags: laravel, security, ads, google-ads-api

This is what the google ads team sent me when i tried running my ads.
"
Investigation:

Post consulting with the wider team, we found that the site has been disabled because we can still find a bad link in the latest system scan.

Below is the link that we’ve detected:

‘amam-zlon[.]com’
"
because of which my website has been marked as malicious website.

Guys i have been working on this project past a really long time and when everything got set finally this is what i got from google i tried checking my c pannel scanning each file one by one but after 2 days of tireless scannin i still just got to 10% of the files. How to fix this problem please help me..